# Excel VBA: TextToColumns on dates (single column, no delimiter) not working?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format a single column full of dates using TextToColumns with no delimiters. The dates are preformatted to `"dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"` and I want to change it to `"dd.mm.yy hh:mm"`

Here's my code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy hh:mm"
    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4), _
      TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

This is the *exact* code that the macrorecorder gives me (and **the procedure works as intended during recording or whenever it is done manually**), with a single exception: `Array(1, 4)` comes out as `Array(1, 1)` in the macro recorder. None of the options work in VBA however.

The thought to try different `Array` values is something I got from Rick Rothstein's answer here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/683477-text-column-not-working-within-macro.html 
Also relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030(v=office.15).aspx

So whenever I run any variant of these snippets, it seems to silently ignore the entire TextToColumn bit. There are no errors or exceptions and it doesn't skip the code line when I step through it -- it runs everything, but for whatever reason, the expected outcome is not achieved.

Example data:

Pre:
`25.06.2015 15:12:20`

Post (expected outcome):
`25.05.15 15:12`

Answer (score 0):

you can use for FORMAT() function in VBA to change date ranges 
See more information in the [LINK HERE](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-format-date/)

Comment: Doesn't that require looping through the range? I think I want to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: @vsoraas  Is there a reason your trying to avoid it? beside the obvious performance costs of iterations.
Also im a little confused, on your post is seems like the issue youre having is that the dates aren't formatting, but it also says the macro basically skips the 'TextToColumn' Function. 
What is the core issue? 
The formatting or that its not parsing the column cells into individual columns?

Comment: The input data is in a single column, as is the output column. I'm not using it to actually parse anything - I am using it to force update the formatting, since this doesn't happen automatically with just setting the numberformat. I have nothing against iterations except the potential performance overhead, and I am already doing many iterations over this dataset so I'd like to not go there again if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work

```
Format(whatEverYouAreChanging.value, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")
```

change whatEverYouAreChanging to your variable, hope this works

or just format the whole columns using a custom format like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: It would probably work for any single value, or an iteration, but I don't want to iterate if I can avoid it.

Comment: @vsoraas in that case why dont you just apply a custom formate to the cells on the worksheet itself? something like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: I can, but it still doesn't update unless I force TextToColumns in some way. I have yet to find a non-iterative method of doing it. Again, using the button that says "Text-To-Columns" solves my problem perfectly and completely - it's just that implementing it in VBA seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If non-looping methods do not work, then use a looping method:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, t As String, d As Date
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        With Cells(i, "G")
            t = .Text
            ary = Split(t, " ")
            bry = Split(ary(0), ".")
            cry = Split(ary(1), ":")
            d = DateSerial(CInt(bry(2)), CInt(bry(1)), CInt(bry(0)))
            d = d + TimeSerial(CInt(cry(0)), CInt(cry(1)), CInt(cry(2)))
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy hh:mm"
            .Value = d
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

And after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gary, I had a similar idea in mind as a back-up, but I am looking for a way to make TextToColumns work before I turn to iteration.